# Suzuki Grand Vitara 2004 wiring

Tags: electrical, battery, wiring, suzuki, grand-vitara

My dad and I just put in a new engine for my Suzuki Grand Vitara.

We connected all the necessary wires and ready to go. When we tried to connect the battery the positive terminal started heating up and melting. So obviously the wiring wasn't correct.

We narrowed it down to the wiring for the starter and the earth wire was in the wrong spot, we are just having trouble finding out where these wires go.

Where does the positive side battery cable get mounted to?

Where does the negative side battery cable get mounted to?

Images of the proper wire routing and points of connection would be helpful.

Comment: Can you take a few pictures of your current situation?  Cheers!  Welcome to the site!

Comment: If you remove the starter wire, but leave the rest, does it make a large spark when you connect the positive cable?

Answer (score 1):

Negative / Grounds go to the body, block and wiring harness

The positive cable for the starter goes on the big lug on the top of the starter similar to this picture:

[image: https://www.wolfsburgwest.com/wired/wired_03_01/starter_jump.gif]

Make sure the battery cable is not cracked and no exposed parts are touching ground, or the body of the starter.